# spring mvc when using *.jsp in urlpattern in web.xml file shows 404 and in console noHandlerFound

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-boot

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>changeinwebxmlinurlpattern</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>


  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>sample</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>sample</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

as welcome file is index.jsp but that request is noHandlerFound means request is searching for controller where it has to return index.jsp.if it is then who to use welcome file. or what mistake i did

Comment: But how index.jsp will call

Answer (score 0):

Change your `url-pattern` to `/`, and you should call your dispatcher servlet as `dispatcher`. Here's an example in my project:

```
   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: thats not my problem my problem is when i use *.jsp  if i will use it will work fine .